# How to get an echo of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php

i got this Code:

```
$Wanteds[] = array(
                'WantedLevel' => 1,
                'WantedName' => "Nichtbefolgen",
                'WantedPreis' => 300
            );
$Wanteds[] = array(
                'WantedLevel' => 1,
                'WantedName' => "Beihilfe",
                'WantedPreis' => 200
            );
$Wanteds[] = array(
                'WantedLevel' => 2,
                'WantedName' => "Dealen",
                'WantedPreis' => 500
            );
```

Now, i tryed to get it into a variable:

```
echo "TESTING: $Wanteds[0][WantedName] <br />";
```

All i got it: TESTING: [WantedName]
instead of: TESTING: Nichtbefolgen

Please keep in mind: I'm new to arrays and programming. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want.

**Echo 1 value**

```
echo "TESTING: " . $Wanteds[0]['WantedName'] . "<br />"; // possibility 1
echo "TESTING: {$Wanteds[0]['WantedName']} <br />"; // possibility 2
```

**Print entire array**

```
print_r($Wanteds); // Usefull for debugging and value checking
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to warb the variable in strings with curly brackets

```
echo "TESTING: {$Wanteds[0]['WantedName']} <br />";
```

Comment: Same here: The string seems to be empty :(

Comment: can you enable the errors in your page and see what happen error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Thanks for this snip! I got a lot of errors, okay, lets go on:

Comment: EDIT: I got the error, im calling echo bevor i created the array x) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, and i got another question, is there a difference using 'text' oder "text" ?

Comment: so if you can please acespt my answer and read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: Well, im new to stackoverflow too, how can ia accept an answer? :)

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I  it's right below the arrows)

Answer (score 0):

No need to print variables in double quotes.

You can print it and concatenate it to string like this:

```
echo "TESTING: " .$Wanteds[0]['WantedName'] ."<br />";
```

Putting variables cause extra load on server as he needs to parse everything inside the string.

Above phenomena is called variable interpolation.

You can use strings without double quotes and that is faster than embedding them in double quotes.

[See it live here](https://eval.in/463567)

Comment: Ah! So, i can use dot (.) to connect Strings or is this just for variables?

Comment: You can concatenate any number/string with dot.

Comment: Just replaced my code with your example, it seems that the string is empty. Do i have another issue to mention?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "TESTING: ".$Wanteds[0]['WantedName']." <br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

To return **the name that you want** you can do the following :

```
echo "TESTING: " .$Wanteds[0]['WantedName'] ."<br />";
```

You could also **display the whole array** with :

```
print_r($Wanteds);
```

Or even **display each sub-array separatly** by doing :

```
foreach($Wanteds as $wanted){
 print_r($wanted);
}
```